# SAPUI5 NavContainer inside sap.m.Dialog Fragement

Tags: sapui5

Is there a possibilty of using a `NavContainer` inside a `sap.m.Dialog fragment`. In PopOver it is possible to have it done but when trying with Dialog nothing is rendered inside the dialog .

**Here is the code :**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Dialog title="Customer Search" type="Message">

    <NavContainer id="navCon">
    <Page id="master" title="Search ">
         <Label text="Customer Name"></Label>
         <Input></Input>

         <Label text="Payer Code"></Label>
         <Input></Input>

        <Label text="Customer City"></Label>
        <Input></Input>

       <Label text="Customer Postal Code"></Label>
       <Input></Input>

       <Label text="SBU" />
       <layout:ResponsiveFlowLayout>
        <RadioButton groupName="supplierCaused" text="Yes" />
        <RadioButton groupName="supplierCaused" text="No" />
        <RadioButton groupName="supplierCaused" text="No" />
       </layout:ResponsiveFlowLayout>

      <Label text="CBT"></Label>
      <Select id="searchCBT" width="100%"></Select>

      <Label text="Region" />
      <layout:ResponsiveFlowLayout>
      <RadioButton groupName="hisTransaction" text="Yes" />
      <RadioButton groupName="hisTransaction" text="No" />
      <RadioButton groupName="hisTransaction" text="No" />
      </layout:ResponsiveFlowLayout>
  </Page>

  <!--
  <Page id="detail" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack"
  title="Product">

     <Label text="Search Results" />

  </Page> -->
  </NavContainer>

   <beginButton>
   <Button text="Random" press="onDialogClose" />
   </beginButton>
   </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be a lot easier for me to answer you via pure javascript. Because in any way you need to attach a open handler to this dialog right? And separating the code will make this rather simple example really complicated one. So would something like that, putted in simple script tags work ?

```
    var btn = new sap.m.Button({text:'Open Dialog', press: function(){oDialog.open();}});

    var oDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
        showHeader : false,
        stretch: sap.ui.Device.system.phone ? true : false,

        beginButton : new sap.m.Button({
            text : 'OK',
            press : function() {
                oDialog.close();
            }
        }),         
        contentHeight : "500px"
    });

    var oNavContainer = new sap.m.NavContainer();
    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        enableScrolling : true,
        title : 'Test Page',
        subHeader : new sap.m.Bar({
            contentMiddle : new sap.m.Button({text:'SubHeader Button'})
        }),
        content : [  new sap.m.Button({text:'Content Button'}) ]
    });     
    oNavContainer.addPage(oPage); 
    oNavContainer.setInitialPage(oPage);
    oDialog.addContent(oNavContainer);

    btn.placeAt('content');
</script>
```

You just need to have an div item with id = "content" and it should work :)